# knockout variable parsing

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

```
  <tbody id="sortable" data-bind="foreach: rows">
    <tr id="tableId" data-bind="foreach: $root.activeColumns">
        <td data-bind="visible:!deleted()">
          <div data-bind="text: ($parent.id)==1"></div>
        </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Hi In my following code if I am printing 'parent.id'
it is printing the id's as 1,2,3,4,5 but if I am writing like '($parent.id)==1' it should print one true and others as false but it is printing false   for all the conditions.I think it is some variable parsing problem.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this? It would better if you posted your knockout view model code as well.

Comment: Perhaps, it should be: ="text: $parent.id() == 1"

Comment: yes i was missing those parenthesis thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have strange view model architecture.
You are using `root` element `activeColumns` and want get `parent` of `root`. Root element havn't parent.

I wrote simplest exemple [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PR3n8/) and it works well.